# Displaying questions & answers from mysql database with php into a html form in the frontend

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms

I have 3 tables in mySQL database.

questions_table with these fields:

1. **question_id** (unique ID for the question)
2. **question_name** (the name of the question)
3. **question_positionID** (the position of
   the question, I need this because
   the admins are able to change the
   positions of the questions in the
   html form in the frontend. I use
   this to display the questions in the
   form appropriately)

questions_users_relationship_table with these fields:

1. **questions_answers** (this is the field
   where it stores what the users
   answered in the frontend form)
2. **user_id** (this is used to connect to
   the users table, when loading the
   specific user's answers to the form)
3. **question_id** (this is used to
   reference the question in the
   questions_table)

users_table with these fields:

1. **user_id** (unique id)
2. **username** (as the name implies, username)
3. **password** (as the name implies, password)

So, erm.. The reason why have these 3 tables in the database is because I have to build an admin section on the website which allows the administrators to switch and change the position of the questions in a form. Therefore the reason for the question_positionID field in the questions_table. I have no problem in listing down the questions and its respective answers in the admin section for the administrators to do the position change ( i used ajax drag n drop to update the mysql table on the question_positionID field)..

My problem lies on the frontend html form itself. Because In the database, I only stored the questions and also its answers in its respective tables.. and did not store what type of questions it is (for example: a gender question might use radio buttons for its answers (Male/Female) or maybe address field which has the Country field with answers in the form of a drop down box).. So, in the frontend html form, I am not sure How to list down the questions and its answers for the respective user_id sorted based on the question_positionID and still would properly display the correct form elements (example: questions with dropdown with list the value in the dropdown boxes, questions with answers in radio buttons would be properly checked in the respective radio buttons, and etc etc)..

I believe many people would love to know how to do it.. I not an expert in PHP and mySQL and slowly learning it through examples and online tutorials.. So I would appreciate it if you guys could shed some light on this question of mine..

Comment: What about storing type of questions in the database?

Comment: Hi Col. Shrapnel.. Thanks for reading through my long questions.. Hope I did not bore you >.<.. Are you suggesting that I should add a field in the questions_table and then store the type of questions? and then I will be able to list down the proper question/answer elements in the frontend form?

Comment: Do not forget that you will have to store the possible answers,too.

Comment: Hi Oliver A, thanks for your input.. I think I sort of caught the idea/concept that both you and Shrapnel suggested but.. If you guys are able to provide a simple example.. using the tables I listed in my question as reference, it would help me to understand and form my own solutions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add another table with answers:

Answer

- answer_id
- question_id
- answer_text

If there are multiple correct answers you will have to add a "is_correct" column to the table as well.

A simple approach to decide how to display the possible answers in the frontend to add a column allow_multiple_answers to your  questions_table and decide whether to use dropdown or radio buttons depending on the number of possible answers.

```
$question//the question
$answers //an array with the possible answers
$maxAnswersForRadio//maximum numbers of oprions to be displayed with radio buttons 
if($question['allow_multiple_answers'){
  //use checkboxes to allow mulltiple answers.
  $html = generateCheckboxes($answers);
}
else{
   if (count($answers<=$maxAnswersForRadio){
      $html= generateRadioButtons($answers);
   }
   else{
      $html=generateDropDownList($answers);
   }
}
```

This is just a example. The sollution depends on the framework/template engine you use.

Comment: Hi Oliver.. Thanks for the quick answer :) Appreciate it.. From what you have suggested, is it alright if I do it this way: I add a new column called "question_type" to my questions_table with the data being enum type with 'text','radio','checkbox','select','textarea'. And when I am displaying the questions in the frontend html, I would use either a FOR or WHILE loop (after getting my sql query) and then within each FOR/WHILE loop, I would use a SWITCH Case or IF/ELSE to detect what question type it is and write the respective answer there.. I hope I'm making sense~

Comment: Yes this should work. However: using a template engine would make things a lot easier. Have look at http://phptal.org/

Comment: Thanks Oliver for the template engine suggestion.. I think im still quite new to template engines so I'll stick to just PHP first.. :)